# Clustering Parallelization Approach in Python for Strings(using Levenshtein as distance) on bigger data set

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, data-science

recently, at work I have been given the task to cluster ~1mio strings by similarity. As distance function I chose Levenshtein, and to cluster it, Agglomerative Clustering.

So far so good, the code worked relatively easy, but the problem I'm now facing is that the distance matrix just gets too big. To parallelize it, I could do batches of let's say 10k x 10k but merging those classification vectors is not possible.

My understanding is that bottom up approaches cannot be easily merged. Could there be a top down approach to cluster them? K-Means does not seem to work with Levenshtein distance, after my research. I hope some people could help me with a new idea to approach the data parallelization problem and how to merge those subset results to a single one.

Greetings, Tony

Comment: If you have a problem where it's too big to fix in memory, you can look at solutions like Dask which is "fits on disk" or in the case of a compute cluster "fits on multiple disks" and I believe dasl_ml supports agglomerative clustering. It's worth a look before you abandon an approach that is working.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, I will look into Dask. The problem is only that creating such a big maxtrix is not possible, because the estimated matrix is 700gb which is way too much. I really need to cut the data in smaller chunks and combine their results. And, as I read, Agglomerative Clustering is not suitable for that kind of clustering.

Comment: 700GB is hefty, but definitely not crazy for Dask. That being said, I cannot recommend a better algorithm.

Comment: What did you end up doing, Tony?